# MySQL hash column on update

Tags: mysql, sql, hash

Data in a `BLOB` column.

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    data BLOB
    md5 CHAR(32)
)
```

I can hash it by doing
`SELECT md5(data) from data`

How to make server store the hash in that column on row update or create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a before insert and before update trigger to the table and set the hash field in the triggers:

```
NEW.md5 = md5(new.data);
```